# Spinner, gridview, asynchronous display

Tags: android, gridview, android-asynctask, spinner

**Background**

Hi, I'm relatively new to android programming. I'm still learning.

I have a database with two tables : Item and Type. Item has the following columns : _id, code, type. Type has the following columns : _id, name.

In my activity, I display a spinner of the types, and a gridview of the items. The spinner is supposed to filter the results and update the gridview.

The gridview items only consist in images. The column code gives the name of the image file.
I have a database helper DatabaseHelper, that opens, close, and access the database in different ways.

At the start of my activity ItemList, getContents() is called, getContents() calls the database, and updates listOfIds and listOfCodes according to the value of selectedType (initialised to 0). Then the gridview is created.

For the gridview, I had memory issues while displaying images and scrolling (out of memory). So I followed the Android tutorial : https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html Now, each item is displayed asynchronously. And it works fine.

**Issue**

When I select a type in the spinner, selectedType is updated, getContents() is called and then notifyDataSetChanged() is called. Sometimes it works fine, sometimes it crashes. I think that when I select a type, old threads that have not been terminated are accessing listOfIds and listOfCodes while they are being updated.

How to kill all of thoses threads (before updating list) and prevent the gridview from calling getView during the update?
I was thinking about creating a list containing the threads, update it, and kill all threads before updating the lists. But I can't find the right way to prevent the gridview's adapter from creating views during the update.

Thank you for your help.

**Code**

Here are parts of my code :

ItemList.java

```
public class ItemList extends Activity {

    private ImageAdapter mAdapter;
    private Bitmap mPlaceHolderBitmap;
    private DatabaseHelper myHelper;
    public static int column = 3;
    public static int MARGIN = 5; //margin in dp
    public static int width;
    public GridView gallery;
    public SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter;
    public Spinner mySpinner;
    public int defaultImageID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.item_list);

        initialiseValues();
        createHelper();
        resetPositions();

        getContents();
        createLists();

        createSpinnerListener();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    public void createHelper() {
        myHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        myHelper.getSpinnerIds();
    }

    public void initialiseValues(){
        myHelper.selectedType = 0;

        //determines the width of the displayed image
        Point size = new Point();
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        display.getSize(size);
        width = size.x - dpToPx(2*column*MARGIN);

        //determines the default image to display
        defaultImageID = ...; //here I get the id of the default image;
        mPlaceHolderBitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), defaultImageID, null, null), width, width);
    }

    public void createList() {
        spinnerAdapter = new SpinnerAdapter(this, myHelper, myHelper.spinnerNames);
        spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
        mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        mySpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

        gallery = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
        mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        gallery.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    public void getContents() {
        myHelper.getLists();
    }

    public void createSpinnerListener() {
        mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                myHelper.selectedType = myHelper.spinnerIds.get(position);
                getContents();
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });

    }

    public int dpToPx(int dp) {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        return Math.round(dp * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
    }

    private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private final Context mContext;

        public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
            super();
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return myHelper.listOfCodes.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup container) {
            View view;
            if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
            }
            else {view = convertView;}

            int image_id = getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(".../" + myHelper.listOfCodes.get(position), null, null);
            if (image_id == 0) {image_id = R.drawable.item_unknown;}

            loadBitmap(image_id, imageView);

            return view;
        }
    }

    public void loadBitmap(int resId, ImageView imageView) {
        if (cancelPotentialWork(resId, imageView)) {
            final BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView);
            final AsyncDrawable asyncDrawable = new AsyncDrawable(getResources(), mPlaceHolderBitmap, task);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(asyncDrawable);
            task.execute(resId);
        }
    }

    public static boolean cancelPotentialWork(int data, ImageView imageView) {
        final BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask = getBitmapWorkerTask(imageView);

        if (bitmapWorkerTask != null) {
            final int bitmapData = bitmapWorkerTask.data;
            if (bitmapData != data) {
                bitmapWorkerTask.cancel(true);  // Cancel previous task
            }
            else {
                return false;   // The same work is already in progress
            }
        }
        return true;    // No task associated with the ImageView, or an existing task was cancelled
    }

    private static BitmapWorkerTask getBitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
        if (imageView != null) {
            final Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
            if (drawable instanceof AsyncDrawable) {
                final AsyncDrawable asyncDrawable = (AsyncDrawable) drawable;
                return asyncDrawable.getBitmapWorkerTask();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

    static class AsyncDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {
        private final WeakReference<BitmapWorkerTask> bitmapWorkerTaskReference;

        public AsyncDrawable(Resources res, Bitmap bitmap, BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask) {
            super(res, bitmap);
            bitmapWorkerTaskReference = new WeakReference<BitmapWorkerTask>(bitmapWorkerTask);
        }

        public BitmapWorkerTask getBitmapWorkerTask() {
            return bitmapWorkerTaskReference.get();
        }
    }

    class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {

        private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

        private int data = 0;

        public BitmapWorkerTask(View view) {
            // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
            imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
        }

        // Decode image in background.
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            data = params[0];
            return decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), data, width, width);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if (isCancelled()) {
                bitmap = null;
            }

            if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
                final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();

                final BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask = getBitmapWorkerTask(imageView);
                if (this == bitmapWorkerTask && imageView != null) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

DatabaseHelper.java

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    ...
    public int currentID = 0;
    public int numberOfItems = 0;
    public List<Integer> listOfIds = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<String> listOfCodes = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<Integer> spinnerIds = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<String> spinnerNames = new ArrayList<>();
    public int selectedType = 0;

    private Context context;
    public SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    ...

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.context = context;
    }

    ...

    public void getSpinnerIds() {
        spinnerIds.clear();
        spinnerNames.clear();
        /*
        updates spinnerIds by accessing the db, first one is "All types"
        */
    }

    public void getLists() {
        listOfIds.clear();
        listOfCodes.clear();
        numberOfItems = 0;

        String where = " WHERE code <> '0'";
        if (selectedPosition != 0) {where += " AND Type = " + String.valueOf(selectedType);}

        openDataBase();
        try {
            Cursor myCursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT _id, code, type FROM Item" + where + " ORDER BY _id ASC", null);
            myCursor.moveToFirst();
            do {
                listOfIds.add(myCursor.getInt(0));
                listOfCodes.add(myCursor.getString(1));
            }
            while (myCursor.moveToNext());
            myCursor.close();
            numberOfItems = listOfIds.size();
        }
        catch (Exception CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException) {}
        myDataBase.close();
   }



    public String getName(int id) {
        String name;
        openDataBase();
        Cursor myCursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM Item WHERE _id = " + String.valueOf(id), null);
        myCursor.moveToFirst();
        name = myCursor.getString(0);
        myCursor.close();
        myDataBase.close();
        return name;
    }

    ...

}
```

SpinnerAdapter.java

```
public class SpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Context context;
    private DatabaseHelper helper;

    public SpinnerAdapter(Context context, DatabaseHelper helper, List<String> list) {
        super(context,  R.layout.spinner_item_small, R.id.text, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.helper = helper;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup prnt) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView);
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView) {
        View view;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item_small, null);
        }
        else {view = convertView;}

        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        textView.setText(helper.spinnerNames.get(position));

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I think I solved my problem by putting synchronized label on all of my database methods.